# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED : certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:1007)'))) - Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

> **PLEASE HELP ME**

For days I haven't been able to understand why I can't configure my hyperledger fabric network with secure SSL communication, due to certificate errors.

I provide you with all the files I use:

network.json (config file for the network)

```
{
"name": "Modbus2Chain",
"description": "Modbus2Chain Project course for IoT security and Data security",
"version": "0.1",
"client": {
    "organization": "Org1",
    "credentialStore": {
      "path": "/tmp/hfc-kvs",
      "cryptoStore": {
        "path": "/tmp/hfc-cvs"
      },
      "wallet": "wallet-name"
    }
},
"organizations": {
"orderer0.modbus2chain.com":{
    "mspid":"OrdererMSP",
    "orderers": [
        "orderer.modbus2chain.com"
      ],
      "certificateAuthorities": [
        "ca-orderer"
      ],
      "users": {
        "Admin": {
          "cert": "../crypto-material/ordererOrganizations/modbus2chain.com/users/Admin@modbus2chain.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@modbus2chain.com-cert.pem",
          "private_key": "../crypto-material/ordererOrganizations/modbus2chain.com/users/Admin@modbus2chain.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
        }
      }
    },
      "org1.modbus2chain.com": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peers": [
          "peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
          "ca-org1"
        ],
        "users": {
          "Admin": {
            "cert": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org1.modbus2chain.com/users/Admin@org1.modbus2chain.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem",
            "private_key": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org1.modbus2chain.com/users/Admin@org1.modbus2chain.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
          }
        }
      },
      "org2.modbus2chain.com": {
        "mspid": "Org2MSP",
        "peers": [
          "peer0.org2.modbus2chain.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
          "ca-org2"
        ],
        "users": {
          "Admin": {
            "cert": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org2.modbus2chain.com/users/Admin@org2.modbus2chain.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org2.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem",
            "private_key": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org2.modbus2chain.com/users/Admin@org2.modbus2chain.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
          }
        }
      },
      "org3.modbus2chain.com": {
        "mspid": "Org3MSP",
        "peers": [
          "peer0.org3.modbus2chain.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
          "ca-org3"
        ],
        "users": {
          "Admin": {
            "cert": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org3.modbus2chain.com/users/Admin@org3.modbus2chain.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org3.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem",
            "private_key": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org3.modbus2chain.com/users/Admin@org3.modbus2chain.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
          }
        }
      }
    },
"orderers": {
    "orderer0.modbus2chain.com": {
      "url": "localhost:7050",
      "grpcOptions": {
        "grpc.ssl_target_name_override": "orderer.modbus2chain.com",
        "grpc-max-send-message-length": 15
      },
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "../crypto-material/ordererOrganizations/modbus2chain.com/tlsca/tlsca.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem"
      }
    }
  },
  "peers": {
    "peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com": {
      "url": "localhost:7051",
      "eventUrl": "localhost:7051",
      "grpcOptions": {
        "grpc.ssl_target_name_override": "peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com",
        "grpc.http2.keepalive_time": 15
      },
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org1.modbus2chain.com/peers/peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem"
      }
    },
    "peer0.org2.modbus2chain.com": {
        "url": "localhost:8051",
        "eventUrl": "localhost:8051",
        "grpcOptions": {
          "grpc.ssl_target_name_override": "peer0.org2.modbus2chain.com",
          "grpc.http2.keepalive_time": 15
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
          "path": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org2.modbus2chain.com/peers/peer0.org2.modbus2chain.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org2.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem"
        }
      },
      "peer0.org3.modbus2chain.com": {
        "url": "localhost:8052",
        "eventUrl": "localhost:8052",
        "grpcOptions": {
          "grpc.ssl_target_name_override": "peer0.org3.modbus2chain.com",
          "grpc.http2.keepalive_time": 15
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
          "path": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org3.modbus2chain.com/peers/peer0.org3.modbus2chain.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org3.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem"
        }
      }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
      "ca-org1": {
        "url": "https://localhost:9050",
        "grpcOptions": {
          "verify": false
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
          "path": "/home/alexcav/go/src/GitHub/Modbus2Chain/crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org1.modbus2chain.com/ca/ca.org1.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem"
        },
        "registrar": [
          {
            "enrollId": "admin",
            "enrollSecret": "adminpw"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ca-org2": {
        "url": "https://localhost:8051",
        "grpcOptions": {
          "verify": true
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
          "path": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org2.modbus2chain.com/ca/org2.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem"
        },
        "registrar": [
          {
            "enrollId": "admin",
            "enrollSecret": "adminpw"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ca-org3": {
        "url": "https://localhost:8052",
        "grpcOptions": {
          "verify": true
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
          "path": "../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org3.modbus2chain.com/ca/org3.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem"
        },
        "registrar": [
          {
            "enrollId": "admin",
            "enrollSecret": "adminpw"
          }
        ]
      }
    }}
```

Here are the configurations of the Docker containers, for the CA and for the organizations (I provide one to give you an idea):

**ca-org1:**

```
    version: "3.8"

volumes:
  ca-org1.modbus2chain.com:

networks:
  apnet:

services:
  ca-org1:
    container_name: ca-org1.modbus2chain.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    volumes:
      - ../crypto-material/caOrganizations/ca-org1.modbus2chain.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - ca-org1.modbus2chain.com:/var/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org1.modbus2chain.com/tlsca:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/tlsca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1.modbus2chain.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_CN=rca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_HOSTS=0.0.0.0
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DEBUG=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/tlsca/tlsca.org1.modbus2chain.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/tlsca/priv_sk
    working_dir: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    command: /bin/bash -c 'fabric-ca-server start -d -b admin:adminpw --port 9050'
    ports:
      - 9050:9050
    networks:
      - apnet
```

**org1:**

```
version: "3.8"

volumes:
  peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com:

networks:
  apnet:

services:
  peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com:
    networks:
      - apnet
    container_name: peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.1
    volumes:
      - ../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org1.modbus2chain.com/peers/peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ../crypto-material/peerOrganizations/org1.modbus2chain.com/peers/peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    environment:
      # Generic peer variables
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt 
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key 
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt 
      # Specific peer variables
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.modbus2chain.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP

      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
```

This is the **python code** I'm trying to run. I'm using the hyperledger-fabric-py SDK and here is where I instantiate the ca_service to register a new user via my admin:

```
import os
from hfc.fabric import Client
from hfc.fabric_ca import CAClient
from hfc.util.crypto.crypto import ecies
from hfc.fabric_network.wallet import FileSystenWallet
from hfc.fabric_ca.caservice import ca_service


cli = Client(net_profile="network.json")
org1_admin = cli.get_user(org_name='org1.modbus2chain.com', name='Admin')
print( org1_admin._enrollment)

ca_certs_path="/home/alexcav/go/src/GitHub/Modbus2Chain/crypto-material/caOrganizations/ca-org1.modbus2chain.com/ca/ca-cert.pem"
casvc = ca_service(target="https://localhost:9050", ca_certs_path=ca_certs_path)

adminEnrollment = casvc.enroll("admin","adminpw") 

secret = adminEnrollment.register("user1") 
user1Enrollment = casvc.enroll("user1", "userpw")
```

When the code gets to:
`casvc = ca_service(target="https://localhost:9050", ca_certs_path=ca_certs_path)`, I get this **ERROR**. I leave it complete below:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3-1.26.15-py3.10.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3-1.26.15-py3.10.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3-1.26.15-py3.10.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3-1.26.15-py3.10.egg/urllib3/connection.py", line 419, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3-1.26.15-py3.10.egg/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3-1.26.15-py3.10.egg/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:1007)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests-2.28.2-py3.10.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3-1.26.15-py3.10.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3-1.26.15-py3.10.egg/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9050): Max retries exceeded with url: /enroll (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alexcav/go/src/GitHub/Modbus2Chain/app/fabric.py", line 19, in <module>
    adminEnrollment = casvc.enroll("admin","adminpw") # now local will have the admin enrollment
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fabric_sdk_py-0.9.0-py3.10.egg/hfc/fabric_ca/caservice.py", line 484, in enroll
    enrollmentCert, caCertChain = self._ca_client.enroll(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fabric_sdk_py-0.9.0-py3.10.egg/hfc/fabric_ca/caservice.py", line 328, in enroll
    res, st = self._send_ca_post(path='enroll',
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fabric_sdk_py-0.9.0-py3.10.egg/hfc/fabric_ca/caservice.py", line 254, in _send_ca_post
    r = requests.post(url=self._base_url + path, **param)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests-2.28.2-py3.10.egg/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests-2.28.2-py3.10.egg/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests-2.28.2-py3.10.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests-2.28.2-py3.10.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests-2.28.2-py3.10.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9050): Max retries exceeded with url: /enroll (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))
```

I appreciate any form of help. Thanks in advance to everyone.